# Display images in datagridview based on data table derived from delimited text file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Newbie when it comes to data tables and datagridview. Have a delimited text file, example lines as follows:

```
;AnalogueJoystick_1;LStick;C:\Users\Steve\Scripts\Projects\CPWizBiz\Code\CPWizBizW\Assets\Images\System_Controller_Components\Sony PSX\LStick #4.png;Steer;LStick;
KEYCODE_A;Button_01;Triangle;;Left Airbrake;Cross;View
KEYCODE_C;Button_03;Square;C:\Users\Steve\Scripts\Projects\CPWizBiz\Code\CPWizBizW\Assets\Images\System_Controller_Components\Sony PSX\Square.png;Ditch Weapon;Square;
```

Note in the middle 'row' the image 'cell' is null.

Also have this code to import the .txt file, convert to a data table and then to datagrid view:

```
Private Sub LoadCSV(CSVFile As String)
    Dim TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(CSVFile)
    TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";")
    Dim TextFileTable As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim Column As DataColumn
    Dim Row As DataRow
    Dim UpperBound As Int32
    Dim ColumnCount As Int32
    Dim CurrentRow As String()

    While Not TextFileReader.EndOfData
        Try
            CurrentRow = TextFileReader.ReadFields()
            If Not CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
                ''# Check if DataTable has been created
                If TextFileTable Is Nothing Then
                    TextFileTable = New DataTable("TextFileTable")
                    ''# Get number of columns
                    UpperBound = CurrentRow.GetUpperBound(0)
                    ''# Create new DataTable
                    For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                        Column = New DataColumn()
                        Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                        Column.ColumnName = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.Caption = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.ReadOnly = True
                        Column.Unique = False
                            TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)
                    Next
                End If
                Row = TextFileTable.NewRow
                For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                    Row("Column" & ColumnCount) = CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString
                Next
                TextFileTable.Rows.Add(Row)
            End If
        Catch ex As  _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & _
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
    TextFileReader.Dispose()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = TextFileTable
End Sub
```

I'm seeking to make column 3 (the image file column) display in the datagridview as an actual image. Also, needs to be able to handle nulls.

Secondly, I'd like to be able to rename the columns from "Column0" "coulmn1" etc to headers of my choice (e.g. "Input Control" "Controller Function" etc....

Could anyone please advise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `DataGridViewImageColumn` to display images from a bound `DataTable` then that table must contain `Byte` arrays in the bound `DataColumn`.  If you want to get a `Byte` array from an image file then you can call `File.ReadAllBytes`.

As for the column headers, you'll have to set those manually after binding.  You can loop through the `Columns` collection of the grid and set the `HeaderText` of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Final Code for anyone in the same boat:

```
Private Sub LoadCSV(CSVFile As String)
        Dim TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(CSVFile)
        TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";")
        Dim TextFileTable As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim Column As DataColumn
        Dim Row As DataRow
        Dim UpperBound As Int32
        Dim ColumnCount As Int32
        Dim CurrentRow As String()

        While Not TextFileReader.EndOfData
            Try
                CurrentRow = TextFileReader.ReadFields()
                If Not CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
                    ''# Check if DataTable has been created
                    If TextFileTable Is Nothing Then
                        TextFileTable = New DataTable("TextFileTable")
                        ''# Get number of columns
                        UpperBound = CurrentRow.GetUpperBound(0)
                        ''# Create new DataTable
                        For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                            If ColumnCount = 3 Then
                                Column = New DataColumn()
                                Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]")

                                Column.ColumnName = "Column" & ColumnCount
                                Column.Caption = "Column" & ColumnCount
                                Column.ReadOnly = True
                                Column.Unique = False
                                TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)
                            Else
                                Column = New DataColumn()
                                Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                                Column.ColumnName = "Column" & ColumnCount
                                Column.Caption = "Column" & ColumnCount
                                Column.ReadOnly = True
                                Column.Unique = False
                                TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)
                            End If

                        Next
                    End If
                    Row = TextFileTable.NewRow
                    For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                        If ColumnCount = 3 Then
                            If CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString <> Nothing Then
                                Debug.WriteLine("Img Path: [" & CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString & "]")
                                Dim img = Image.FromFile(CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString)
                                Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
                                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                                Row("Column" & ColumnCount) = ms.ToArray
                            End If
                            Debug.WriteLine("Img Null")
                        Else
                            Row("Column" & ColumnCount) = CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString
                        End If
                    Next
                    TextFileTable.Rows.Add(Row)
                End If
            Catch ex As  _
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & _
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
        TextFileTable.Columns(0).ColumnName = "Input Code"
        TextFileTable.Columns(1).ColumnName = "Rig Control"
        TextFileTable.Columns(2).ColumnName = "Final Controller Functions"
        TextFileTable.Columns(3).ColumnName = "Image"
        TextFileTable.Columns(4).ColumnName = "Final Game Function"
        TextFileTable.Columns(5).ColumnName = "Default Controller"
        TextFileTable.Columns(6).ColumnName = "Default Game Functions"
        TextFileTable.Columns(7).ColumnName = "Type"

        TextFileReader.Dispose()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = TextFileTable
    End Sub
```